# How to specify experiment-id in my python script when running project using `mlflow run`

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow

I am using mlflow to track a bunch of runs in my python script.
In my script, I have some lines to specify the experiment  (checks for name and Id) under which the runs will be performed:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
exps = mlflow.search_experiments()
exp_names = [e.name for e in exps]
if EXP_NAME in exp_names:
   experiment_id = exps[exp_names.index(EXP_NAME)].experiment_id
else:
   experiment_id = mlflow.create_experiment(EXP_NAME)
print(f"Created New Experiment > ID: {experiment_id}")
experiment = mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_id=experiment_id)
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="fantastic-run", experiment_id=experiment_id):
    ....
   [ mlflow.endrun() ]
```

This work as expected when run using:

```
python my_python_script.py
```

But, when I add an entry  (`my-entry`) in my MLproject file that call the same command and I run (in commandline) `mlflow run -e my-entry path_to_my_mlflow_project/`. The default experiment (id=0) is chosen and throws an error when the script tries to set a new experiment:

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Cannot start run with ID 4552f1852c0d4eafae72b84d38af7346 because active run ID does not match environment run ID. Make sure --experiment-name or --experiment-id matches experiment set with set_experiment(), or just use command-line arguments

ERROR mlflow.cli: === Run (ID '4552f1852c0d4eafae72b84d38af7346') failed ===
```

How to tell mlflow from command-line to use the experiment created in the script?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the experiment name in the command line using

```
mlflow run . --experiment-name=<experiment_name>
```